# How is audio encrypted?

Tags: encryption

I was wondering how is audio encrypted. I know about other data files but dont have any idea about audio files. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would there be a difference? Data is data...

Comment: Audio data is a sequence of bytes, you encrypt it like any other sequence of bytes.

Comment: Well, my audio files aren't. Sometimes I wonder a bit about the trash-metal ones but so far I haven't found any proof.

Comment: Are you asking about a specific file format, like how a particular vendor implements DRM?

Comment: I mean like if we are doing whatsapp live call, so how data is encrypted and decrypted real time..?

Comment: @zeeshandossani you take the bits produced by the mic, take 100ms or so of this, cram this into a packet and encrypt and send that. You reverse the process and output the sound on the receiving end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For educational reasons, I suggest you look at how IPSec's Encapsulating Security Payload is constructed.  There is an IV (for whatever mode of encryption is employed), ciphertext, an authentication tag, and a counter.  For each packet the sender increments the counter so if all is well on the network then packets will arrive with sequential count values.

The receiver remembers the keys to enable authentication and decryption but also remembers two other important datums: a base count and a bit mask.  The base count is the oldest count that will be accepted.  The bit mask indicate if the count at `baseCount + bitPosition` have been received.  The receiver can accept packets out-of-order (up to the size of the bitmask) without being exposed to replay attacks.

Your question has gone unanswered for a while in part because it is unclear.  Most of encrypting realtime data is still just traditional cryptography.  There are engineering tricks to improve performance and handle things like dropped or out-of-order packets, but that is arguably a different topic than cryptography (e.g. network engineering).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to understand that there are analog audio (the ones in 3.5mm cables), and digital audio (Dolby Digital, Linear PCM, DTS, etc.). We can easily encrypt and decrypt digital audio because they're encoded as a sequence of bytes.

Anyway, I suppose this might be more appropriate a question for engineering SE.